# Javascript TypeError appears randomly: Cannot read property 'AdditionalQueryParameters' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure-mobile-services

I am building an angluarjs (NG) + Azure Mobile Service (AMS) application and I have an NG service where I perform all my AMS calls as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673003/integrating-the-mobileserviceclient-with-angularjs). Currently, I am trying to put together simple code to test out reading and writing from my AMS.

Here is my NG service code:

```
myModule.factory('AzureMobileClient', function () {

var azureMobileClient = {};
//azureMobileClient.isLoggedIn = false;
azureMobileClient.azureError = "";
azureMobileClient.azureMSC = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("[SERVICE URL]", "[SERVICE API KEY]");

azureMobileClient.getSimpleTest = function (callback) {
    var spUser = azureMobileClient.azureMSC.getTable("User").read({ majorId: "200", minorId: "201" }).done(function (items) {
        callback(items)
    },
    function (err) {
        azureMobileClient.azureError = err;
        console.log(azureMobileClient.azureError);
    });
}

return azureMobileClient;
```

});

Here is my NG controller code:

```
controllers.testing = function ($scope, Data, AzureMobileClient) {

$scope.data = Data;

$scope.testClick = function () {
    AzureMobileClient.getSimpleTest(function (items) {

        if (items.length == 0) {
            console.log('no items found');
        }
        else {
            $scope.$apply($scope.items = items);
            console.log($scope.items);
        }
    });
}

$scope.outputData = function () {
    console.log($scope.data);

}

$scope.outputAzure = function () {
    console.log(AzureMobileClient.AzureMC);
};
```

}

And here is my html code:

```
<div style="background-color: #CCCCCC" ng-controller="testing">
                    <h2>Testing Area</h2>

                    <button ng-click="testClick()">Test Azure</button>
                    <br />
                    <button ng-click="outputData()">output data to console</button>
                    <br />

                    <button ng-click="outputAzure()">output azure to console</button>
                    <br />
                </div>
```

Now, sometimes this code will just work and an HTTP GET request will be logged in the browser developer tool. But most of the times, the exact code will cause an error that appears in the browser console and HTTP GET request will not be fired.

[image]

Comment: If you do not pass anything in the read function does it work? `.getTable("User").read()`

Comment: @PSL I just tried .getTable("User").read() for several times and it seems to work just fine. What does that mean?

Comment: @PSL Any idea on why is this happening?

Comment: That constant is supposed to be defined globally (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/search?l=javascript&q=AdditionalQueryParameters&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

It looks like its not being found, a bug possibly specific to use in Angular.js? The quickest option for now, would probably be to remove that constant, or fall back to a version before it was added (is possible for you)

Do you know what version you are using now?

Comment: @phillipv Here is my Azure script tag <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.5.min.js"></script> it shows **MobileServices.Web-1.2.5.min.js**, is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Yes, 1.2.7 is the newest version, and 1.2.4 does not have the offending line (AdditionalQueryParameters) yet.  Can you try 1.2.7 and if that has the same issue fall back to 1.2.4?  If you want to do debugging to see if you can get any additional details, remove the '.min' portion to use the unminified copy of the JS file.

Comment: I tried 1.2.7 and it produced the same error and I have been using 1.2.4 without any issue since yesterday. So, I guess I will stick with 1.2.4 for now!

Comment: @phillipv Can you please log your suggested comment as an answer so I can accept it.